# jcryption form submit not working with button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jcryption

I am using jcryption for encrypting the form.It works fine if i use submit button in form. Instead if i use button and submit the form manually my jcryption method is not getting called.

```
below is my code





<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {

       $("#login").bind('click', function(){

       document.authenticatorform.username.value=$("#username").val();
       document.authenticatorform.password.value=$("#password").val();
        alert('outer hello');
        $("#authenticatorform").jCryption({
                            getKeysURL:"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/keypairrequest",
                            beforeEncryption:function() {
                            alert('inner hello');
                             document.authenticatorform.submit()
                                return true; },
                            encryptionFinished:function(encryptedString, objectLength) {return true;}
        });

       });


    });
    </script>

    <body>

    <form:form method="post" action="login.htm" name="authenticatorform" id="authenticatorform">
    <input type="hidden" name="username"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="password"/>
    </form:form>

    <input type="button" id="login"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

In the code only outer alert is printing.

Is it possible to call jcryption in other than submit button?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using **on** click function instead of **bind**

```
    Try this:
    $("#login").on('click', function(){
       //your codes goes here
    }
```

Comment: @S Dhanissh, the code goes inside the bind block but not calling jcryption method